# Two Exchange Accounts, One Tile

Tags: 8.0, tiles, exchange

I have a primary exchange account for work. I also have a secondary account that I must monitor for customer support emails. I would like to have one live tile for each account, but Windows Phone 8 jams them together and doesn't let me add a tile for the second one.

Is it possible to have one tile per exchange account?

Comment: So it turns out that I am (or Microsoft is) a big idiot. A new tile got created for the new email account that I didn't see. All works fine with that tile if you know to scroll all the way down on the main screen to find it.

Comment: you can also pin individual folders if you like.  not thinking that this one is msft's fault.

Answer (score 1):

If you hit the ... menu from the inbox/tile on your home screen, you should be able to view "linked inboxes." From there you should be able to unlink them, unless there is something weird with two exchange accounts. I'm guessing it just linked them by default for you.

Comment: Unfortunately they're not linked. It did give me the option to link them in the "link inboxes" menu.

Comment: if you have two seperate email accounts and they are not linked you should find each one in the app-list.